# What is the dfifference between instance dict and class dict

Tags: python

I was reading the python descriptors and there was one line there

> Python first looks for the member in the instance dictionary. If it's
>   not found, it looks for it in the class dictionary.

I am really confused what is instance dict and what is class dictionary

Can anyone please explain me with code what is that

I was thinking of them as same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An instance dict holds a reference to all objects and values assigned to the instance, and the class level dict holds all references at the class namespace.

Take the following example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    def foo(self, bar):
...       self.zoo = bar
...
>>> i = A()
>>> i.__dict__ # instance dict is empty
{}
>>> i.foo('hello') # assign a value to an instance
>>> i.__dict__ 
{'zoo': 'hello'} # this is the instance level dict
>>> i.z = {'another':'dict'}
>>> i.__dict__
{'z': {'another': 'dict'}, 'zoo': 'hello'} # all at instance level
>>> A.__dict__.keys() # at the CLASS level, only holds items in the class's namespace
['__dict__', '__module__', 'foo', '__weakref__', '__doc__']
```

Comment: thanks Burhan , that was the explanantion i was looking for . Like we dynamically assign the instance dict. can we dynamically assign the class dictionary

Comment: i.z = some_val ... I want to learn more about this expression. I mean I though I'm limited to attributes I create in the __init__ function, but seems not. What exactly is this ?

Answer (score 6):

I think, you can understand with this example.

```
class Demo(object):
    class_dict = {}   # Class dict, common for all instances

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.instance_dict = d   # Instance dict, different for each instance
```

And it's always possible to add instance attribute on the fly like this: -

```
demo = Demo({1: "demo"})
demo.new_dict = {}  # A new instance dictionary defined just for this instance

demo2 = Demo({2: "demo2"})   # This instance only has one instance dictionary defined in `init` method
```

So, in the above example, `demo` instance has now `2` instance dictionary - one added outside the class, and one that is added to each instance in `__init__` method. Whereas, `demo2` instance has just 1 instance dictionary, the one added in `__init__` method.

Apart from that, both the instances have a common dictionary - the class dictionary.

Comment: i don't get , how can we add attribute outside the class. new_dict is not the data member in the class

Comment: @user9 That's how it works in Python. You can add instance data  members on the fly, outside the class's `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

Those dicts are the internal way of representing the object or class-wide namespaces.

Suppose we have a class:

```
class C(object):
    def f(self):
        print "Hello!"

c = C()
```

At this point, `f` is a method defined in the class dict (`f in C.__dict__`, and `C.f` is an *unbound method* in terms of Python 2.7).

`c.f()` will make the following steps:

- look for `f` in `c.__dict__` and fail
- look for `f` in `C.__dict__` and succeed
- call `C.f(c)`

Now, let's do a trick:

```
def f_french():
    print "Bonjour!"

c.f = f_french
```

We've just modified the object's own dict. That means, `c.f()` will now print `Bounjour!`. This does not affect the original class behaviour, so that other `C`'s instances will still speak English.

Comment: Can you tell me what is unbound method and what is bound method

Comment: @user9 Sure. You may have noticed that you always have to declare that annoying `self` argument in each method, but don't have to pass it when calling a method. When you get `func = instance.method`, some magic happens underneath, so that `func` is bound to the instance and does not need `self` (it can be called just as `func()`). That's called a bound method. On the other hand, `Class.method` is also callable but unbound (unaware of the instance), so you have to call it explicitly as `Class.method(instance)`.

Comment: In your code C.f is an unbound method , can you give me example where you can declare bound instance method inside the class

Comment: @user196264097 you can't declare a bound method inside a class, that's in fact an oxymoron, if I understand your question correct.

Answer (score 1):

Class dict is shared among all the instances (objects) of the class, while each instance (object) has its own separate copy of instance dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can define attributes separately on a per instance basis rather than for the whole  class

For eg.

```
class A(object):
    an_attr = 0

a1 = A()
a2 = A()

a1.another_attr = 1
```

Now a2 will not have another_attr. That is part of the instance dict rather than the class dict.

Answer (score 0):

[Rohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain) has the simplest python code to explain this quickly.  However, understanding the same ideas in Java can be useful, and there is much more information about class and instance variables [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)